# Some confusion on backup whole data in redis

Tags: redis, backup

Document say:
Whenever Redis needs to dump the dataset to disk, this is what happens:
Redis forks. We now have a child and a parent process.
The child starts to write the dataset to a **temporary RDB file**.
When the child is **done writing the new RDB file**, it **replaces the old one**.

Because I want to backup whole data, I type `shutdown` command in redis-cli expecting it shutdown and save all data to `dump.rdb`.After it shutdown completely, I go to db location and see what happen that `dimpr.rdb` is 423.9MB and `temp-21331.rdb` is 180.5MB.Temp file is still exist and smaller than `dimpr.rdb`.Apparently, redis do not use temp file  replaces `dump.rdb`.

I am wondering whether `dump.rdb` is whole db file at this time?And is it safe to delete the temp file.

Answer (score 0):

What does the file mod timestamp of `temp-21331.rdb` say? It sounds like a leftover from a crash.
You can delete it.

The documentation is definitely correct. When rewriting, all info is written to a temp file (compressed), and when complete, the `dump.rdb` file is replaced by this temp-file. There should however be no leftovers during normal usage. What *is* important: you always need enough free disk space for this operation to succeed. A safe guideline is: 140% times the redis memory limit (it would be 200% if no compression was applied).

Hope this helps, TW